# Глагол с корнем мощь?

Tags: словообразование

Есть ли глагол с корнем мощь? Может быть «мощнеть»?

Answer (score 4):

Глагол с таким корнем есть: **умощнять**. Его можно найти даже в словаре Даля (в значении придания кому-л. большей власти или *полномочий*). В современном языке он широко применяется в технике в значении повышения механической прочности или электрической *мощности устройства* или его элемента. Такое значение фиксируется современными словарями.

"*Мощнеть*" изредка можно встретить в разговорной речи (об откорме домашних животных) или как окказионализм в некоторых текстах, но нормативное выражение со значением, которое хотят таким словом выразить - "*становиться мощнее*". Столь же ограниченное употребление и просторечный оттенок имеет глагол "*сильнеть*" (вместо "становиться сильнее" или "набираться сил"), фиксируемый некоторыми словарями (Толковый словарь Ефремовой, 2000) как "разг.".

Answer (score 0):

***МОЩ***У  — 1 лицо, ед. число от [***МОСТ***ИТЬ](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)

Answer (score 0):

В глаголе "мочь" тот же корень, но с точки зрения главенствующего синхронистского подхода эти слова не однокоренные, а родственные.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37325/discussion-on-answer-by-----).